# Samsung Notebook 900X3D cannot enter bios setup

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, microsoft-office, samsung-laptop

I reset my Samsung notebook 900X3D and it said error during reset and it restarted and upon restarting it just shows the Samsung logo screen and restarts and I cant enter into bios using <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, or any F .  How do I fix it?

Comment: The key is F2 according to the user's manual. Trying others that can't possibly work is a waste of time. Immediately after powering on spam the key. If Fast Boot is enabled the time windows for that is very small, a second or less after pressing the power button. Also note that if it has a function keys switch feature and you enabled it then you may need to do FN+F2.

Comment: You don't have a "BIOS", you have UEFI firmware.   Try holding down shift when you tell windows to restart.  Use logic to climb your way to the firmware settings screen.